# TypeError at object of type 'int' has no len() in Django

Tags: sql-server, django, django-rest-framework, pyodbc

In stored procedure I'm passing the parameter as int in Django API where I'm getting this error. I have no issue in passing string in others API only when I pass the int

Error:

```
TypeError at  object of type 'int' has no len() in Django
    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\shalman.samiulla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\decorators.py", line 50, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Downloads\API\app\views.py", line 303, in ClaimReferenceView
    cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[sp_GetClaims] @UserId=%i', (10))
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\base.py", line 549, in execute
    sql = self.format_sql(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\base.py", line 517, in format_sql
    sql = sql % tuple('?' * len(params))

Exception Type: TypeError at /api/Data/GetClaims/10
Exception Value: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

views.py

Here I have to pass the userid to the stored procedure in the URL as well so that it will reflect particular rows from the different tables through the stored procedure.

As of now, I have given the id directly but I want to pass the requested userid to the stored procedure.

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def ClaimReferenceView(request, userid):
    
    try:
        users = Tblclaimreference.objects.filter(userid=userid)
       
    except Tblclaimreference.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == 'GET':
 
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[sp_GetClaims] @UserId=%i', (10))
        result_set = cursor.fetchall()
   
        return response(result_set, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

StoredProceure:

```
USE [ECS]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_GetClaims]    Script Date: 14-Dec-21 3:13:06 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetClaims] ---exec [dbo].[sp_GetClaims] 17                                
@UserId int                             
                                 
AS                                      
BEGIN                                      
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from                                      
-- interfering with SELECT statements.                                      
SET NOCOUNT ON;                                     
   select                   
             
   --ISNULL([Fields],'') as [Fields],        
   ISNULL([Number],'') as [Number],         
   ISNULL([Opened],'') as [Opened],        
   ISNULL([Contact type],'') as [Contact type],        
     ISNULL([Category 1],'') as [Category 1],        
   ISNULL([State],'') as [State],        
  ISNULL([Assignment group],'') as [Assignment group],        
  ISNULL([Country/Location],'') as [Country/Location],        
  ISNULL([Opened for],'') as [Opened for] ,        
  ISNULL([Employee number],'') as [Employee number],        
       ISNULL([Short description],'') as [Short description]   ,      
        ISnull(cast([loadedOn] as date) ,'') as AllocatedDate
        
        FROM [dbo].[tblSourceHrEcs]            
 where 1=1                    
 --and Stat_date is not null                 
 and isplayed = 0                     
  and [Assigned to] = (select AID  from tblusers where UserID = @UserId  
       )    
  order by [Opened]                 
                           

   End
```

Comment: Does it work better with square brackets? i.e.: `cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[sp_GetClaims] @UserId=%i', [10])`

Comment: I have tried with square bracket as well but I'm getting an error as " sql = sql % tuple('?' * len(params)) TypeError: %i format: a number is required, not str "

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the issue

> cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[sp_GetClaims] @UserId=%i', (10,))

Adding a comma in the tuple resolved it